# Group by two columns in Rcharts nPlot

Tags: r, rcharts

I try to group by two variables in nPlot. I would like to get interactive Legend for both of this variables so I can filter on both variables.
My code in R for single group variables looks as follows:

```
    require(devtools)
    install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')
    library(rCharts)
    r1<- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = 'cyl', data = mtcars, type="scatterChart")
    r1$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e,graph){
    return '<b>carb</b>: ' + e.point.carb
    } !#")
    r1$chart(size = '#! function(d){return d.disp} !#')
    r1
```

I try to use something like this for 2 columns bu t it's not working:

```
    r2<- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = c('cyl','gear'), data = mtcars, type="scatterChart")
    r2$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e,graph){
    return '<b>carb</b>: ' + e.point.carb
    } !#")
    r2$chart(size = '#! function(d){return d.disp} !#')
    r2
```

I also try adding but it doesn't give me the posiibility to filter on both variables at one time:

```
    r2$addControls("group", value = "gear", values = names(mtcars))
```

Is there a way to make such plot. Thanks.

Comment: as far as I know, nvd3 does not support multiple groups.  Would dimple.js be an option since it handles easily and is also MIT licensed?  Will be happy to do demo if so.  If I understand the the second piece about addControls, then support of only one group level in nvd3 would answer that question.  Let me know.  Glad you are playing with rCharts.

Comment: addControls are not necessary in my case. I get partial answer from rCharts creator- Ramnathv. `library(rCharts)
mtcars = transform(mtcars, gear_cyl = paste(gear, cyl, sep = "_"))
r1<- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = 'gear_cyl', data = mtcars, type="scatterChart")
r1$addFilters("gear", "cyl")
r1`